# Android Crashlytics sending incorrect line number

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to integrate Crashlytics with my app and it's working, however the line number passed through seems to be incorrect. This is a stack I'm getting for my test exception:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: This is a test crash
   at com.myapp.testapp.activity.MainActivity.animateReveal(MainActivity.java:42453)
   at com.myapp.testapp.activity.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:1356)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

So my crash is on line number 1453 but for some reason it's showing up as 42453? Interestingly, the next line number in the stack is correct...

Proguard:

```
# Crashlitics

-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Answer (score 3):

To preserve the information that Firebase Crashlytics SDK requires for producing readable crash reports, add the following lines to your Proguard or Dexguard config file:

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable        # Keep file names and line numbers.
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception  # Optional: Keep custom exceptions.
```

Answer (score 1):

Likely it's because you're using a *release* build which will remove comments/ white spaces.

If you're using a *debug* build then it *may* show the correct lines, because it won't optimize your source code...

Still I'm guessing there is another reason for the line numbers to show incorrect, because Fabric was telling me the crash was happening at line 400, even though that function was called at line 300. I mean if comments and white spaces are to be removed, Fabric should have told line some line **less** than 300, not more!

Answer (score 1):

In my case switching from 'proguard-android-optimize.txt' default proguard file to 'proguard-android.txt' fixed the issue. Using the optimized version of the proguard file can introduce certain risks and it seems that this is one of them.

Comment: I should try this!

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, a simple observation solve my issue, see proguard-rule and uncomment these line
(-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable)

and

(-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

> For Fabric to properly de-obfuscate your crash reports, you need to
> **remove this line** from your configuration file, or we won’t be able to automatically upload your mapping file:
>
> -printmapping mapping.txt

and

> -keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
>
> -dontwarn com.crashlytics.**

Comment: my setup conforms to that and the issue is still present

Comment: post full proguard file

Comment: I'm afraid I can't but it's a standard one around Fabric (following their docs). The only thing is that it's based on Android SDKs one with optimisations and I'm not sure if the issue didn't start to appear since we switched to SDK's optimised one as default for our config.